# NSCache isn't returning data the first time it's asked

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, caching

for my app i have to convert some HTML into NSAttributedStrings in tableViews. This is a very CPU intensive operation so i decided to leverage NSCache to effectively cut this time in half since the HTML is converted twice, once to measure the size of the cell and once more to draw the cell.

The problem is that the first time the cache is queried for the object, it returns nil like if it was never sent to the cache.

Both requests are made on the same queue (main), i have verified that the cache key is the same and that the cache in use is the same. What am i doing wrong?

There is my code:

```
#import "HITProduct+Cache.h"

@implementation HITProduct (Cache)

static NSCache *cache;

- (NSAttributedString *)attributedString
{
    @synchronized(cache) {
        if (!cache) {
            cache = [NSCache new];
            cache.evictsObjectsWithDiscardedContent = NO;
            cache.countLimit = 10;
        }
    }

    NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString;
    @synchronized(cache) {
        attributedString = [cache objectForKey:self.title];
    }

    if (!attributedString) {
        attributedString = [[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[self.title dataUsingEncoding:self.title.fastestEncoding] options:@{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute : NSHTMLTextDocumentType} documentAttributes:nil error:nil] mutableCopy]; //This is very slow

        @synchronized(cache) {
            [cache setObject:attributedString forKey:self.title];
        }
    }

    return [attributedString copy];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you try this code (no @synchronized and ARC enabled):

```
- (NSAttributedString *)attributedString {
    if(self.title == nil){ return nil; }

    static NSCache *cache = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        cache = [NSCache new];
        cache.evictsObjectsWithDiscardedContent = NO;
        cache.countLimit = 10;
    });


    NSAttributedString *attributedString = [cache objectForKey:self.title];
    if (!attributedString) {
        attributedString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[self.title dataUsingEncoding:self.title.fastestEncoding]
                                                            options:@{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute : NSHTMLTextDocumentType}
                                                 documentAttributes:nil error:nil];

        [cache setObject:attributedString forKey:self.title];
    }

    return attributedString;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData is still called twice for the same self.title :(

Comment: Can you try adding more logs, are you sure title second time does not have for example whitespace ?

Comment: It's the exact same memory address, i think the string coalescing would create a new object for a different string?

Comment: If it's same address and it's immutable string then key is same. No idea why it does not work for you, try replacing NSCache for NSDictionary, if then the value is stored ok would appear that NSCache is removing the object which you dont use (as in measure the property is never saved).

Comment: There are no such things as mutable strings in objc, ill try with a dictionary.